# Raycast get local coordinates of hit of Plane

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a plane with scale (64,1,36) and rotation is (90,-180,0) and need the local coordinate of a raycast hit in the 2d coordinates format:

```
(0,0)-------(64,0)
 |             |
 |             |
 |             |
(0,36)------(64,36)
```

with my current code:

```
RaycastHit hit;
Vector3 coords = new Vector3();
if (Physics.Raycast(GazeOriginCombinedLocal, GazeDirectionCombined, out hit, Mathf.Infinity))
    {
        if (!hit.transform.Equals("Cube"))
        {
            Pointer.transform.position = hit.point; //Green cube for visualization of hit in worldspace
            // coords = RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle(Plane, hit.point, Camera.main, out coords);// no result at all
        }

       
    }
```

Trying this:

```
hit.transform.InverseTransformPoint(hit.point)
```

gives me this

```
(5,-5)---(-5,-5)
  |         |
  |  (0,0)  |
  |         |
(5,5)----(-5,5)
```

Does some have an idea to get the needed format?

Thats how my plane which is a child of the main camera and my hierarchy looks like:
[image]
[image]
[image]
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please edit the question to include a [mre]. This should include the hierarchy of all relevant gameobjects and any attached colliders or other components.

Comment: Please include the transform (especially showing the scale) of the `Camera` gameobject.

Comment: The scale of the Camera is (1,1,1). I've added a photo of it, thats why I didnt find the solution, because the numbers seems to be so randomly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could use the [`Transform.InverseTransformPoint`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.InverseTransformPoint.html) which

> Transforms position from world space to local space.

And then since this also is affected by the scale multiple it again by the scale of the plane using [`Vector3.Scale`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Scale.html).

So your coords should probably be something like

```c#
coords = hit.transform.localScale / 2f +  Vector3.Scale(hit.transform.InverseTransformPoint(hit.point), hit.transform.localScale);
```

---

*can't test it right now though since typing on smartphone. You might e.g. need to invert the y/z component according to your needs and depending how the plane is rotated etc. But I hope this gives you an idea*

In order to debug what's wrong you should probably print out the values step by step

```c#
var scale = hit.transform.localScale; // 64, 1, 36
var halfScale = scale / 2f; // 32, 0.5, 18

var localHitPoint = hit.transform.InverseTransformPoint(hit.point);
Debug.Log($"{nameof(localHitPoint)}:{localHitPoint:0.000}");
```

So what I had expected originally here would be values like

```c#
(-0.5, 0.5, 0)----(0.5, 0.5, 0)
       |                |
       |   (0, 0, 0)    |
       |                |
(-0.5, -0.5, 0)---(0.5, -0.5, 0)
```

**BUT** as you now added: Your plane is **rotated!**

The 90° on X actually makes that Y and Z switch places. So in order to get the desired Y coordinate you would rather read the `localHitPoint.z`.

Then the 180° on Y basically inverts both X and Z.

So I would now expect the values to look like

```c#
(0.5, 0, -0.5)----(-0.5, 0, -0.5)
       |                |
       |   (0, 0, 0)    |
       |                |
(0.5, 0, 0.5)---(-0.5, 0, 0.5)
```

Which looks pretty much like the values you describe you are getting. *Not sure though why you have a factor of 10 and why you didn't need to switch Y and Z.*

However since you actually want the 0,0 to be in the top-left corner you only need to flip the X axis and use Z instead of Y so

```c#
fixedLocalHitPoint = new Vector2(-localHitPoint.x, localHitPoint.z);
Debug.Log($"{nameof(fixedLocalHitPoint)}:{fixedLocalHitPoint:0.000}");
```

Which should now give you values like

```c#
(-0.5, -0.5)----(0.5, -0.5)
       |             |
       |   (0, 0)    |
       |             |
 (-0.5, 0.5)----(0.5, 0.5)
```

And still you need to scale it up again

```c#
var scaledHitPoint = Vector2.Scale(fixedLocalHitPoint, new Vector2 (scale.x, scale.z));
Debug.Log($"{nameof(scaledHitPoint)}:{scaledHitPoint:0.000}");
```

Which should now give values like

```c#
(-32, -18)----(32, -18)
     |             |
     |   (0, 0)    |
     |             |
 (-32, 18)-----(32, 18)
```

That's why you need to add the center point as a reference

```c#
coords =  new Vector2(halfScale.x, halfScale.z) + scaledHitPoint;
Debug.Log($"{nameof(coords)}:{coords:0.000}");
```

Which now should be

```c#
(0, 0)------(64, 0)
   |            |
   |  (32, 18)  |
   |            |
(0, 36)-----(64, 36)
```

I hope this brings a bit more light into where these "strange" values come from.

---

Since your camera is scaled `1,1,1` and there is nothing else involved I have a hard time finding where the factor of 10 would have sneaked its way into the calculation to be honest.

Comment: I've edited my post, with the result of your code, as it does not work as intended. The plane has not RectTransform, so the pivot is in the middle but the result of the InverseTransformPoint is pretty strange

Comment: I updated to use local scale instead .. it sounds like your plane has some parents that are scaled differently? Can you check again? Seems a bit unfair btw that you accept the other answer that basically took all my stuff I already have put thoughts in and just hot-fixed the values with some hardcoded multipliers ....

Comment: The parent (The main camera) is not scaled and at the orginal postition, so using lossyscale=localscale leads sadly to the wrong result.

Comment: @Dadium I have added some further ideas at the bottom.aybe the help to understand why you are getting strange values. One of the main reasons is the local rotation of your plane which causes the axis to be flipped .. I'm still trying to find out why yours are a factor of 10 off ...

Comment: Super cool, that's helping a lot, thank you very much. With strange values I' talking about, the same things as you are having problems with. In the scene there is nothing more than the plane being attached to the camera to face always to the user. However this solves my problem, so maybe I will find the reason later, but for now I'm happy.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to convert this:

```
hit.transform.InverseTransformPoint(hit.point)
```

which gives this:

```
(5,-5)---(-5,-5)
  |         |
  |  (0,0)  |
  |         |
(5,5)----(-5,5)
```

to this:

```
(0,0)-------(64,0)
 |             |
 |             |
 |             |
(0,36)------(64,36)
```

Why not do this:

```
Vector2.Scale(
        hit.transform.InverseTransformPoint(hit.point) - new Vector2(5,-5),
        new Vector2(-6.4, 3.6) 
        );
```

This answer hardcodes the `(5,-5)` and `(-6.4, 3.6)` terms because the question doesn't include enough information to use variables instead.

Assuming the scale of the parent of the plane (Main Camera) is (10,10), then this should suffice:

```
Vector3 planeScale = hit.transform.localScale;
Vector3 cameraScale = hit.transform.parent.localScale;

result = Vector2.Scale(
          hit.transform.InverseTransformPoint(hit.point) 
        - new Vector2(cameraScale * 0.5f ,-cameraScale * 0.5f),
        new Vector2(-planeScale.x * 0.5f/cameraScale.x, planeScale.y * 0.5f / cameraScale.y) 
        );
```

Comment: (-6.4,0, 3.6) was the key to go... lossyscale which is (64,1,36) gave the wrong result, thanks

Comment: Sounds like a hot-fix though .. if you look closer you see that these values are basically lossyScale but with x inverted and devided by 10 .. sounds like some parent is scales differently and you should probably rather use `localScale` .. I changed this in my answer .. to me it sounds a little bit unfair to accept an answer which is basically completely based on the stuff I put already a lot of thoughts in just hot-fixed with some hardcoded multipliers... ;) Not that I don't like you Ruzihm :D

Comment: I agree, upvote if you think my answer is helpful but please don't accept it. and I can delete this answer if you think that is more fair @derHugo . I didn't see that asker only put in the `Trying this:` part only after you suggested it.